# Exporting image to excel with farpoint spread

Tags: asp.net, spread, farpoint

I'm trying to export to excel of a cell with an image. The image doesn't appear in the excel file. Is it possible that this feature is not supported?

```
        imageCell = New ImageCellType
        imageCell.ImageUrl = "..."
        Sheet.Cells(0, 0).CellType = imageCell
```

I'm using Farpoint.Web.Spread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't supported.  Here's a list of all the cell types and what's exported to excel files.

http://helpcentral.componentone.com/NetHelp/SpreadNet7/ASP2/spweb-excelexport-celltype.html